# r 3.4.1 source exprs

Tags: r

I have following function as example:

```
 myFunc <- function(x){
  while(x < 100){
  x <- x+10
    cat( x )
    cat("\n")
  }
}
```

In the new R version 3.4.1 on Windows I want to source this function from the file **myFunc.R** like as below:

```
filepath <- "D:/"
l <- list.files(filepath, pattern = "my", full.names = TRUE)
source(l)
```

But am getting the following Error:

> ```
> source(l) Error in source(l) :    could not find symbol "exprs" in
> environment of the generic function
> ```

I hope anyone can help. Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the contents of l before passing it to source

Comment: `> l
[1] "D:/myFunc.R"`

Comment: So `source("D:/myFunc.R")` returns the same error? What does `environment(source)` return for you?

Comment: Is the code provided the only thing in the myFunc.R file?

Comment: `envirnment(source)` returns:                                                     `<environment: 0x000000000fbd9e78>`
`Note: no visible binding for global variable 'x' `
`Note: no visible binding for global variable 'envir' `

Comment: @Dason: Yes, this is the only thing provided.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.